# How to loop through Azure Datalake Store files in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, databricks

I am currently listing files in `Azure Datalake Store gen1` successfully with the following command:

```
dbutils.fs.ls('mnt/dbfolder1/projects/clients')
```

The structure of this folder is

```
- client_comp_automotive_1.json [File]
- client_comp_automotive_2.json [File]
- client_comp_automotive_3.json [File]
- client_comp_automotive_4.json [File]
- PROCESSED [Folder]
```

I want to loop through those (`.json`) files in this folder and process them one by one, so that I can act on error or something else and move successfully processed file to a subfolder.

How can I do this in `python`. I have tried

```
folder = dbutils.fs.ls('mnt/dbfolder1/projects/clients')
files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

But this does not work. `os` is unknown. How can I do this within `Databricks`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer was simple even when i searched for two days:

```
files = dbutils.fs.ls('mnt/dbfolder1/projects/clients')

for fi in files: 
  print(fi.path)
```

Answer (score 4):

Scala version of the same (with ADLS path)

```
val dirList = dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<DIR_PATH>/")

// option1
dirList.foreach(println)

// option2
for (dir <- dirList) println(dir.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way that translates seamlessly to a local installation of python is:

```
import os
os.listdir("/dbfs/mnt/projects/clients/")
```

Comment: It says 'No such file or directory' though I can see the dir using dbutils.